# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE error 13 on a Pi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use the LOAD DATA INFILE MySQL command on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. There are lot of similar questions on here but none seems to answer my problem exactly.
My code works fine on my Windows dev machine but on the Pi I get this error:

```
Can't get stat of '/var/www/transfer/categories.csv' (Errcode: 13)
```

Mysql statement is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE  '/var/www/transfer/categories.csv'
  IGNORE INTO TABLE category
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

The code is running in PHP and the database is MySQL.

The file and its '/transfer' folder have read permissions for World.

I have read a little about apparmor but can't see how to check or change how it is configured. There are 2 files in the /etc/apparmor.d folder. One is .usr.sbin.mysqld.swp but it doesn't seem to contain text and the other file refers to lightdm.

The database server and client is on the same server, so the LOCAL keyword doesn't apply.
My MySQL user has global privileges, so includes the FILE privilege.
I have checked the secure_file_priv setting and there is none.

I am sure this is some sort of permission or privilege issue, but I've run out of ideas. I want the file to live under the www folder because the system user has FTP rights to put it there. Ultimately I want to also create the file on the same machine but for now I'm happy to just read the file created under Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ errno 13
EACCES 13 Permission denied
```

Check your permissions; especially folder permissions. You can try `su` or `sudo -u` to the MySQL user and running `ls -la /var/www/transfer/`; if you don't see anything then you know the issue has to do with permissions of the folder and/or its contents.

If MySQL is running locally; to see which user: `ps -elf | grep mysql`

To switch to the MySQL user and test: `sudo -u <mysql> bash`

Comment: Thanks jersten. I am not sure how to log on as the MySQL user - have no idea what the password is. As far as I can see, the folder and CSV files have R permission for World. drwxrw-rw- 2 pi pi     4096 May  6 16:39 transfer

Comment: Thank you jersten, that solved it. It was a permission thing - I had the transfer folder set as 744 and it needed to be 755.